# OData - $expand on navigation property of non navigation property

Tags: odata, olingo

For example a simple structure:

```
 MyEntity
   - Property1 (identifier)
   - Property2 (Complex-Type)
      - Property3
      - NavigationProperty1
      - NavigationProperty2
   - NavigationProperty3
   - NavigationProperty4
```

I want to query `/MyEntity(1)?$expand=Property2/NavigationProperty1` but our (Olingo) Server ignores the entire expand part of the URL and returns the `MyEntity` entity without the `NavigationProperty1` property.

Should it be possible at all to expand a navigation property of a non navigation property?

Comment: Interesting. I wasn’t aware that navigation props as part of a complex type can exist at all! You CAN chain navigation props like `Orders?$expand=ToPositions,ToPositions/ToProduct`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [OData Version 4.0 URL Conventions](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.pdf#page=37) point out it should be possible to expand a navigation property of a complex type or an entity type.

[image: Screenshot page 37]